# Pyarmor pack and obfuscate subfolder files

Tags: python, obfuscation, pyarmor

In my folder, I have my main.py file. In the folder, there's also subfolders with more .py files. If I run:

```
pyarmor pack -e " --onefile" main.py
```

Does the .py files in the subfolders also get obfuscated?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried checking the documentation for `pyarmor`?